# Is there any way to Login/Signup with twitter or Linked in Cognito

Tags: oauth, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I am using Cognito for the user management and I want to let the user authenticate with Twitter or Linkedin

Answer (score 1):

Not directly as neither Twitter nor LinkedIn are OIDC IdPs. People have had some success shimming the required resources in lambda to turn non-standard identity providers into OIDC compliant ones. The most actively developed is [TimothyJones/github-cognito-openid-wrapper](https://github.com/TimothyJones/github-cognito-openid-wrapper).

It is a good starting point for you to adapt LinkedIn and Twitter for your needs.